# How should I organize multiple static objects with similar methods?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, virtual, static-methods

I'm making a tile-based train game in C#, and I've decided that the track types should be written as static classes (in my mind, every "Straight" track should exhibit the same behavior, as should every "LargeTurnLeft", "SmallTurnRight", etc.)

The train follows the track by passing a variable "w" into whatever kind of track it is currently riding. Each type of Track has a function called trackLogic that returns different (X,Y) coordinates based on the shape of the track. "trackLogic" is always available for each type of track, but the function differs from type to type (sometimes it returns a straight line, sometimes a curve, maybe a loop-the-loop).

In my mind, the best way to organize this is to have a static, virtual "Track" with functions that are overridden with the specific methods for each kind of track ("LargeTurnRight.trackLogic", etc). This would make making new track types easier. But, as I'm sure y'all already know, static, virtual classes don't exist in C#.

Because this game will eventually involve thousands and thousands of track pieces, I don't want instances of each one. But for multiple track types to have a uniform function structure, they can't be static either.

Should I scrap the individual classes, throw switch cases in the original "Track" class for each type, and update the function with each new piece, or is there a more elegant way to organize multiple functions with the same method name?

Comment: These kind of questions help with code. However in my mind, tracks should only hold the basic amount of information, the locations, dimensions, type, ect. they should be immutable seemingly, probably suited to a struct, kept in an array or list or something. and some other class should be dealing with any other logic, like your train, add pepper and salt to taste.

Comment: I would not generally be concerned about thousands of objects candidly. My recommendation would be design the structure you want and measure if there is an actual concern before you compromise the design you would like to have. It would help to post samples of your code and to spell out what you are worried about in more detail.

Comment: Thank you, TheGeneral and Mirko. Its a small starter project, so I already had the design I wanted in the non-static versions, but I wanted to push my skills and try shrinking it. From what I've heard about static classes elsewhere, it sounds like putting the logic into the train is the best option (since multiple trains accessing the same static functions for, say, "straight track" at the same time might cause errors), but since I'm still single-threading this I'll try out a single trackLogic class and go from there.